# Probability that first card being one higher than the number on the second card

Tags: probability, probability-theory

#### Question

> $\text{A deck of 5 cards (each carrying a distinct number from 1 to 5) is shuffled}$
> $\text{ thoroughly. Two cards are then removed one at a time from the deck. }$
> $\text{What is the probability that the two cards are selected with the number}$
> $\text{ on the first card being one higher than the number on the second card?}$

#### My Approach

> Total number of possiblities in selecting $2$ cards$=5 \times 4=20$

---

> Total number of possiblities in selecting $2$ cards where first card being one higher than the number on the second card $=10$

i.e $(2,1),(3,1)(3,2)(4,1)(4,2),(4,3)(5,1)(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)$

So the answer should be $\frac{10}{20}=\frac{1}{2}$

But it is given as -: $\frac{1}{5}$

Please help

Comment: Note that the question says "one higher" and not just "higher" so the possibilities are $(2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (5, 4)$

Comment: @MarkBennet thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in none of 
$$(3, 1), (4,1), (5, 1), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5)$$
is the first card *one* higher than the second card. So those shouldn't be counted. You are left with
$$
(1, 2),(2, 3),(3, 4),(4, 5)
$$
which are four possibilities, meaning that the probability of picking one of these possibilities is $\frac{4}{20} = \frac15$.

Comment: Ahh I missed it ..It is exactly +1 higher.If it would be just higher then my answer willl be correct?

Comment: @laura Yes, in that case your answer would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The number in the top card should be **one higher** than the second one. So, the only possibilities are: $$(5,4), (4,3), (3,2), (2,1)$$ giving us 4 cases, so the probability is $\frac{1}{5}$.